# Extracting vcf columns substring with awk

Tags: bash, awk, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I have vcf file like this:

```
##bcftools_annotateVersion=1.3.1+htslib-1.3.1
##bcftools_annotateCommand=annotate 
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  HG005
chr1    817186  rs3094315   G   A   50  PASS    platforms=2;platformnames=Illumina,CG;datasets=3;datasetnames=HiSeq250x250,CGnormal,HiSeqMatePair;callsets=5;callsetnames=HiSeq250x250Sentieon,CGnormal,HiSeq250x250freebayes,HiSeqMatePairSentieon,HiSeqMatePairfreebayes;datasetsmissingcall=IonExome,SolidSE75bp;callable=CS_HiSeq250x250Sentieon_callable,CS_CGnormal_callable,CS_HiSeq250x250freebayes_callable;AN=2;AF=1;AC=2 GT:PS:DP:ADALL:AD:GQ    1/1:.:809:0,363:78,428:237
chr1    817341  rs3131972   A   G   50  PASS    platforms=3;platformnames=Illumina,CG,Solid;datasets=4;datasetnames=HiSeq250x250,CGnormal,HiSeqMatePair,SolidSE75bp;callsets=6;callsetnames=HiSeq250x250Sentieon,CGnormal,HiSeq250x250freebayes,HiSeqMatePairSentieon,HiSeqMatePairfreebayes,SolidSE75GATKHC;datasetsmissingcall=IonExome;callable=CS_HiSeq250x250Sentieon_callable,CS_CGnormal_callable,CS_HiSeq250x250freebayes_callable;AN=2;AF=1;AC=2   GT:PS:DP:ADALL:AD:GQ    1/1:.:732:1,330:99,391:302
```

I need to extract ID column and  AN from INFO column to get:

```
ID         INFO
rs3094315   2
rs3131972   2
```

I'm trying something like this `awk '/^[^#]/ { print $3, gsub(/^[^AN=])/,"",$8)}' file.vcf`, but still not getting the desired result.

Comment: ID should be relatively easy to extract by the position in row, but AC would probably require some regular expression. gsub (or other from the family) function is your friend here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual reminder, there are dedicated tools for this kind of thing and there's no reason to use something like awk or sed, especially if you are a beginner and you don't really understand what the command is doing, as there are many pitfalls of parsing vcf files. There's every reason to think an awk script will silenty fail on a new/previous version of the vcf format in some weird and wonderful.

Simple bcftools solution:

```
bcftools query -f'%ID [%AN]\n' in.vcf > out.txt
```

`bcftools format` extracts fields from the vcf. Within the `-f` formqt flag, for `INFO` fields, use the format `%FIELD` and for `FORMAT` fields, use the format `[%FIELD]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
/^##/{next}
/^#/{print $3,$8; next}
{
    split($8,a,";")
    for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++) if (a[i]~/^AN=/) {sub(/^AN=/,"",a[i]); break}
    printf "%s%s%s\n", $3, OFS, a[i]
}
' file
```

With the example, prints:

```
ID  INFO
rs3094315   2
rs3131972   2
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU `sed` is maybe a better choice for this:

```
$ sed -En '/^#/!s/^(\w+\t){2}(\w+).*;AN=([^;]+).*/\2\t\3/p' file.vcf
rs3094315    2
rs3131972    3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 mawk NF=NF OFS='\t' FS='^##.+|^[^ \t]+[ \t]+[^ \t]+[ \t]+|[ \t]' \
               '.+(FILTER[ \t]+|;AN=)|([ \t]+[^ \t]+[ \t]+[^ \t]+|;.+)$'
```

---

```
    ID  INFO    
    rs3094315   2   
    rs3131972   2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F' *|AN=|;AF=' 'NR>2{print(NR==3 ? $3"\t\t"$8 : $3"\t"$9)}' file
ID              INFO
rs3094315       2
rs3131972       2
```